# How to access super class field without cast when it can be ensured that the type is the same as the sub class?

Tags: java, generics, nodes

I have the following code. Can I access the `number` property in the method `doSomething` of the class `DjikstraNode` without a cast somehow with generics? I can ensure that the list `edges` only contains items with the type `DjikstraNode`.

```
public class Node {
    protected List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<>();
}
public class Edge {
    public Node source;
    public Node destination;
}
public class DjikstraNode extends Node {
    public int number;

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(((DjikstraNode)edges.get(0).source).number);
    }
}
```

Comment: No.  If you want to do that, you should declare `edges` as `List<DjikstraNode>`.

Comment: @ganti - nit: his name is spelled *Dijkstra*.

Answer (score 0):

If `Edge` class will always contain only `DijkstraNode`, then you don't need generic types at all. Just change `source` and `destination` to `DijkstraNode` (like @markspace mentioned in the comment).

But if you want to make it more flexible and working with any `Node` implementation, then you need to pass subclass type to super class. In below code, `Edge` class is parametrized and accepts any type extending `Node` type (assuming `source` and `destination` fields in given `Node` object have always the same type).

```java
    public class Node<T extends Node> {
        protected List<Edge<T>> edges = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public class Edge<T extends Node> {
        public T source;
        public T destination;
    }

    public class DjikstraNode extends Node<DjikstraNode> { // typo in your code here: Dijkstra
        public int number;

        public void doSomething() {
            System.out.println(edges.get(0).source.number);
        }
    }
```